# Raster grid on PostGIS not able to add to QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster

I am using PostgreSQL 12.2/PostGIS 3.0.1 and QGIS 3.1.

I'm trying to do the example on PostGIS Cookbook by uploading the Temperature Grid exactly as shown in the book (https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781849518666/1/ch01lvl1sec16/importing-raster-data-with-the-raster2pgsql-postgis-command)

```
$ raster2pgsql -I -C -F -t 100x100 -s 4326 worldclim/wc2.1_10m_tmax_01.tif tmax01 > tmax01.sql
$ psql -d postgis_cookbook -U me -f tmax01.sql
```

The upload seems to be successful (I'm using PostgreSQL 12.2/PostGIS 3.0.1) on Windows 10 platform (Localhost).

However, when trying to add the resulting image from the database into QGIS 3.12, I get the following error on top of the viewer window:

> Invalid Layer: Raster layer Cannot instantiate the 'postgresraster'
> data provider

Any clues?

Comment: Your version of QGis isn't compiled for PGRaster surport

Comment: Thank you for responding Ian, Is there anything I can do to rectify this?