# Unable to load raster from PostGIS into QGIS - Cannot instantiate the postgresraster data provider

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm hoping this is a simple problem. I'm trying to visualise the raster layer I have loaded in PostGIS, using QGIS. I've seen other people simply open the QGIS DB Manager and drag the raster layer into the QGIS layers panel. But when I try that I get the following error appearing saying Raster layer cannot instantiate the postgresraster data provider.

[image]

I see someone else had the same problem at [Raster grid on PostGIS not able to add to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361647) but the only comment was:

> Your version of QGIS isn't compiled for PGRaster surport

which I don't know how to interpret or fix and neither did the original question asker.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found to the problem was completely re-install QGIS.